# C# mysql reader.read()

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy tratando de leer tomar el *idphone* de la tabla *phone*, pero el **reader1** recoge el dato de esta tabla rara vez y casi siempre no lo hace.

Corroborando que los datos que estoy buscando existan en dicha tabla con el patrón de búsqueda.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Db query = new Db();
            query.Query("INSERT INTO phone(meid,iccid) VALUES('" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["ICCID"].Value +
            "','" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["MEID"].Value + "')");
```

Este es el primer **reader** y si recoge los datos que necesito de la base de datos

```
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone_atrribute WHERE sku='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["SKU"].Value + "'", GetConexion());
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Este es el segundo y el que me esta dando problemas el dato es un entero y aveces lo recoge pero es muy raro que ocurra, no logro ver por que funciona algunas veces y otras no.

```
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone WHERE meid='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["MEID"].Value + "'", GetConexion1());
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

Aqui intento insertar los datos recogidos por el **reader** y el **reader1** en la base de datos, pero ya que el **reader1** no recoge el dato esto no se ejecuta.

```
           if (reader.Read() && reader1.Read())
            {
                int phone = reader.GetInt32(0);
                int attribute = reader1.GetInt32(0);

                query.Query("INSERT INTO phone_inventary(phone,phone_attribute) VALUES('"+phone+"','"+attribute+"')");
                reader.Close();
                reader1.Close();

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el problema es que usas dos métodos diferentes para abrir la conexión, `GetConexion()` y `GetConexion1()`, y dentro del primero estas cerrando la conexión, puedes usar un solo método.

Por el problema que comentas que en ocasiones si obtienes datos y en otras no en este punto:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone WHERE meid='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["MEID"].Value + "'", GetConexion1());
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

Me parece que la conexión se esta cerrando al realizar linea de código, dentro de `GetConexion()`

Puedes usar el mismo método de conexión para las 2 consultas pero asegura cerrar la conexión hasta terminar las operaciones.

```
 connexionBD.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahora estoy utilizando el mismo método para ambas consultas pero aun sigo recibiendo el mismo problema, cambie el orden de las consultas y las comprobé para ver si era un problema de connection o ejecución pero la única consulta que no trabaja es.

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone WHERE meid='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["MEID"].Value + "'", GetConexion1());
        MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

De la primera consulta siempre obtengo el resultado deseado.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone_atrribute WHERE sku='" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["SKU"].Value + "'", GetConexion());
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Aun no se con exactitud donde puede estar el error ya que eh comprobado todo lo que se me ocurre.

Comment: Si la pregunta es tuya, edita la pregunta en lugar de dar una respuesta, ya que aun no es parte de la solución.

Comment: Edward, mi pregunta es porque usan 2 métodos para realizar la conexión : GetConexion() y GetConexion1(), pueden usar únicamente un método y al terminar únicamente cierran la  conexión. me parece que dentro de GetConexion() se esta cerrando la conexión por esa razón en ocasiones la consulta con el segundo método de conexión no obtiene resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Si el es un número entero y el campo es numérico no deberías utilizar comillas en la consulta:

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone WHERE meid=" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["MEID"].Value, GetConexion1());
MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

Y mejor aún si usas parámetros:

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT idphone FROM phone WHERE meid=@meid", GetConexion1());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meid", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["MEID"].Value);
MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```